# Is it possible to end a process nicely in a Java application?

Tags: java

In a Java application:

```
currentProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("MyWindowsApp.exe");
...
currentProcess.destroy();
```

Calling `destroy` simply kills the process and doesn't allow any user cleanup or exit code to run. Is it possible to send a process a `WM_CLOSE` message or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Process.getOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream()) to send a message to the stdin of your app, eg:

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(currentProcess.getOutputStream());
ps.println("please_shutdown");
ps.close();
```

Of course this means you have to contrive to listen on stdin in the Windows app.

Comment: Thanks, of all the solutions, this one seems the best!

Answer (score 3):

you can try with JNA, importing user32.dll and defining an interface that defines at least `CloseWindow`

Comment: +1 JNI maybe? I wonder if there's a utility like 'kill -SIGTERM' in Windows

Answer (score 3):

Using JNA's jna.jar and process.jar (from http://jna.java.net/) you send a WM_CLOSE message as follows:

```
int WM_CLOSE = 0x10;

HWND hwnd = User32.INSTANCE.FindWindow(null, windowTitle);
User32.INSTANCE.PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, new WinDef.WPARAM(), new WinDef.LPARAM());
```

Answer (score 2):

Not without resorting to native code. `Process.destroy()` causes a forced termination. On Windows this is equivalent to calling `TerminateProcess()`. On Unix it is equivalent to a `SIGQUIT` and causes the application to core dump.

Comment: SIGKILL doesn't dump core! It's not SIGQUIT (which does dump core by default).

Comment: I stand corrected. I guess Unix versions of Java must send a SIGQUIT (core dumps definitely occur). I'll update this answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A dirty solution would be making your MyWindowsApp register its identifier somewhere like file and create another windows app that sends WM_CLOSE (let's name it MyWindowsAppCloser) to another applications.

With this in hand, you would code the following using java 1.6

```
currentProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("MyWindowsApp.exe");
...

// get idMyWindowsApp where MyWindowsApp stored its identifier
killerProcess = new ProcessBuilder("MyWindowsAppCloser.exe", idMyWindowsApp).start();
killerProcess.waitFor();

int status = currentProcess.waitFor();
```