# Is there a better way to work with processes in Java rather than parse tasklist and send "kill" signals?

Tags: java

I'm looking for a good way to work with processes (in Windows, but probably in Linux too).

Is there any pure java solution?

Or at least a cross platform library that does all the parsing?

I need to:

- see if program is running
- send a "close" signal to it (not kill)
- start it (that's probably the only thing I got solved)

All solutions I find say I should parse a tasklist in Windows.

But that's a real pain in the butt.

Anyone done something like this?

Comment: Wouldn't this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912282/java-tool-method-to-force-kill-a-child-process?rq=1

Comment: There is no such thing as a "close" signal... What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Try to use [JSVC](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html)

Comment: fge: in Windows when you click "close" button - it tells program to close. so the program does all "before-close" and "after-close" callbacks and then closes. pretty sure it exists

Comment: Erik: this requires manually writing the actual command line commands. Isn't there a more abstract way?

Comment: Damian0o: how exactly JSVC can help? it seems it just gives root privileges, no?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to end a process nicely in a Java application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955248/is-it-possible-to-end-a-process-nicely-in-a-java-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On linux :** `jps` will provide you a list of only Java processes running including pid or `ps -aux | grep '<program name or part of program name>` for all the processes and you can then use `kill -15 <pid>` to kill, which gives a normal shutdown signal.

[Check this link](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_gracefully_kill_%28close%29_programs_and_processes_via_command_line) for what kill -15 does, if you aren't sure.

**On windows:** `taskkill /pid <pid> or taskkill /im app.exe` will gracefully send the shutdown signal to a running pid. `jps` is valid for windows too and for all process you can `try TASKLIST /fi "imagename eq <app>.exe"`

Comment: I need to check&close a 3rd party program. It's not on Java.

Comment: Check I modified. Will it help?

Comment: thanks - that's how I have it right now.. and it causes problems.

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: Kill -15 and taskkill /pid <pid> will close programs releasing all the resources properly. So where is the problem now?

Comment: Parsing tasklist causes freezing on some platforms (say if I have non-English Windows 7). Taskkill sometimes needs to be triggered two-three times.

Comment: So, tasklist is a system command which is provided by Windows. You can probably try working with Windows API to deal with this problem further and make your own implementation. Check this for an example - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18962/Kill-Application-Using-Win32-APIs

Comment: thanks, I wrote a batch file like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script